# How does adding dont_filter=True argument in scrapy.Request make my parsing method to work ?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

Here's a simple scrapy spider

```
import scrapy

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["https://www.dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = ('https://www.dmoz.org/')

    def parse(self,response):
        yield scrapy.Request(self.start_urls[0],callback=self.parse2)

    def parse2(self, response):
        print(response.url)
```

When you run the program, parse2 method doesn't work and it doesn't print response.url. Then I found the solution to this in the thread below.

[Why is my second request not getting called in the parse method of my scrapy spider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34805344/why-is-my-second-request-not-getting-called-in-the-parse-method-of-my-scrapy-spi)

Its just that I needed to add dont_filter=True as argument in request method to make the parse2 function work.

```
yield scrapy.Request(self.start_urls[0],callback=self.parse2,dont_filter=True)
```

But in the examples given in scrapy documentation and many youtube tutorials, they never used dont_filter = True argument in scrapy.Request method and still their second parse functions works.

Take a look at this

```
def parse_page1(self, response):
    return scrapy.Request("http://www.example.com/some_page.html",
                      callback=self.parse_page2)

def parse_page2(self, response):
    # this would log http://www.example.com/some_page.html
    self.logger.info("Visited %s", response.url)
```

Why can't my spider work unless dont_filter=True is added ? What am I doing wrong ? What were the duplicate links that my spider had filtered in my first example ?

P.S. I could've resolved resolved this in the QA thread I posted above, But I'm not allowed to comment unless I have 50 reputation (poor me !!)

Comment: Is there a reason why you are downloading the same page twice? Scrapy filters your requests so you don't end up crawling the same pages, `dont_filter` quite literarily means to ignore this filter for this one request.

Comment: Not related to your question, but could bite you soon enough: `allowed_domains` should list domains, not URLs, so it should be `allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Short answer:** You are making duplicate requests. Scrapy has built in duplicate filtering which is turned on by default. That's why the `parse2` doesn't get called. When you add that `dont_filter=True`, scrapy doesn't filter out the duplicate requests. So this time the request is processed.

**Longer version:**

In Scrapy, if you have set `start_urls` or have the method `start_requests()` defined, the spider automatically requests those urls and passes the response to the `parse` method which is the default method used for parsing requests. Now you can yield new requests from here which will again be parsed by Scrapy. If you don't set a callback, the `parse` method will be used again. If you set a callback, that callback will be used.

Scrapy also has a built in filter which stops duplicate requests. That is if Scrapy has already crawled a site and parsed the response, even if you yield another request with that url, scrapy will not process it.

In your case, you have the url in `start_urls`. Scrapy starts with that url. It crawls the site and passes the response to `parse`. Inside that `parse` method, you again yield a request to that same url (which scrapy just processed) but this time with `parse2` as the callback. When this request is yielded, scrapy sees this as a duplicate. So it ignores the request and never processes it. So no calls to `parse2` is made.

If you want to control which urls should be processed and which callback to be used, I recommend you override the `start_requests()` and return a list of `scrapy.Request` instead of using the single `start_urls` attribute.

Comment: I think you mean overriding `start_requests` since `get_start_urls` is not a thing in your last paragraph.

Comment: My bad, yes, I am updating the answer. I was writing from memory and forgot the name.

Comment: I never thought that urls in `start_urls` are parsed automatically. Thanks so much for your help and time

Comment: Doesn't the filtering apply to scrapy.FormRequest  too?