# Is it correct in Scrapy to have multiple parse methods in one spider?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

Is it correct in Scrapy to have multiple parse methods in one spider ?

Something looking like:

```
import scrapy


class FooSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'foo'
    start_urls = ['https://example.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        ...
        yield {'foo': foo}

    def parse(self, response):
        ...
        yield {'bar': bar}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can create different methods and call them from `start_requests` for example.

```py
import scrapy


class FooSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'POC'
    start_urls = ['https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/detail_basic/']

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.get_title, dont_filter=True)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.get_price, dont_filter=True)

    def get_title(self, response):
        yield {'title': response.xpath('//h3/text()').get()}

    def get_price(self, response):
        yield {'price': response.xpath('//div[@class="card-body"]/h4/text()').get()}
```

Comment: It seems that it only runs the first method, not the second one.

Comment: @Elias I forgot to add `dont_filter=True`, see the edit.

Comment: In fact it works if I don't follow the next page link for each method. If I try to follow it, it only considers the first called method. An idea on how to solve that issue ?

Comment: Adding `dont_filter= True` to `follow_all` solved my issue but I'm wondering if adding `dont_filter = True` everywhere is a good idea ...

Comment: You don't have to add it everywhere, just where you need it.

Comment: An interesting [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38951878/how-does-adding-dont-filter-true-argument-in-scrapy-request-make-my-parsing-meth) to understand `dont_filter`